# How can I close Form1 if I closed Form2?

Tags: vba, formclosing

When I close Form2, Form1 is still running in the background and the debugging does not stop. I have a button in Form1 that opens Form2 and makes Form1 unvisible.

Is there a simple solution to shut Form1 down whenever I close Form2 and then make the whole program close? (without any button in Form2)

Comment: Are you using Windows Forms? If so you can hook into the Form.Closed or Form.Closing event for Form2 and close the program in the corresponding event handler.

Comment: `Unload Form1` should do the trick, but if you are closing the entire application anyway, then that should automatically close all the forms too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call `Application.Quit` when closing Form2.
If you are using a UserForm:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Terminate()
    Application.Quit
End Sub
```

If you are using an Access form:

```
'Close event on Form2
Private Sub Form_Close()
    DoCmd.Close acForm, "Form1", acSaveNo
    Application.Quit
End Sub
```

Note that `Application.Quit` will really quit the application. If you just want to close the form, use `Unload Form1` instead (also, called within one of these blocks of code).

Comment: But where do I call it from? And where do I put it?

Comment: I edited my response. You might only want to use the DoCmd (if you're using Access) and not the Application.Quit, which closes everything.